# how get All threads From Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i use this code

Get 1 result

not All Database Threads

when use echo $articles ;  Post 1 record

```
include_once 'clude/conn.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM exploit";

$q = mysql_query($sql);

$num_row = mysql_num_rows($q);

$articles = mysql_fetch_array($q);
mysql_close();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
           Test
        </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="color: red;"><a href="exploit.php?id=<?php echo $articles['id']; ?>"><?php echo $articles['title']; ?></a></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

now i need How Get All Records

Comment: call `mysql_fetch_array` more than once, in fact, `$num_row` times?  Each time the array should be the next row.  Don't close until you've read all rows.

Comment: use while loop for get you all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use while Loop to get your all records.

In my solution i use while loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exploit";

$q = mysql_query($sql);

$num_row = mysql_num_rows($q);

while($articles = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {

?>


        <h1 style="color: red;"><a href="exploit.php?id=<?php echo $articles['id']; ?>"><?php echo $articles['title']; ?></a></h1>


<?php 
} 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Also mysql_* function are deprecated, so use mysqli_* instead.